# Dragon maze (collect stars and exit)

Tags: mazes

Here is a maze I found in a book. Normally I wouldn't think a maze is really hard enough to be worth this site, but I can guarantee this one will take atleast 15 minutes to solve.

You must enter from the start arrow, collect all the stars, and exit at the exit arrow. You may not retrace or intersect your path.

[image]

Comment: The image leaves a little to be desired....

Comment: Is this one of those impossible "puzzles"?

Comment: I barely see the start arrow. And I don't see the stars

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The image quality is *really* bad, so I made my best guess for what counts as a "star". I marked those spots with blue below.

> [image: solved]

The full path is **green+yellow**. I used green/red to mark must/can't paths that I could deduce immediately, then yellow/purple as a second step. The more paths you mark, the less there are to try :)

Comment: Sorry for the image quality, but its hard to take a good shot with a webcam. Anyway, your version of the maze, as well as the answer is correct. Congrats!

Comment: +1 for the strategy of removing passages that can't be part of the solution. It's a good insight that there are some paths that won't work regardless of which direction you enter then from.